# How to iterate and calcualte average of columns in pandas dataframe pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

[image]

I have a `Dataframe` pivot table like above (above image is a excel screenshot which I created manually keeping the df in mind). There are other rows and columns too with similar format.

I have to calculate the average of each column for each section. For example, the output from the above table would be -

```
2020-06-30 -> avg(2.3, 1.5, 3.4, 8.5) | avg(3.1, 1.6, 3.1) | avg(1.4, 3.2) | avg(0.5)
2021-06-30 -> avg(0.32, 0.43, 1.2, 0.56) | ...
```

Comment: A sample ready dataframe? [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Seems like you wanna use `groupby` -> Try: `df.groupby(level = 0).mean()`

Comment: @Corralien the dataframe gets generated after multiple steps. I will try to get some MRE.

Comment: Its hard to provide a solution without an example, but this seems like a grouby.mean(). I would not do this through iteration.

Answer (score 0):

i think this can help you :

```
df.pivot_table(values = '' , index = '' , columns = '' , aggfunc = np.mean , fill_value = 0 , margins = True)
```

This argument `margins = True` calculates the mean of each column and row and shows it in the new column.

Comment: I already have the pivot table as `df`, which is coming from a different process. I can't change that. I can only access the pivot `df`.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this on my own data frame and it worked :

```
average_column = pivot_table_df.loc[ : , : ].mean() #average off all columns
```